# Matlab transfer functions

Tags: control-system, matlab, digital-control

I used the "c2d" to discretize a transfer function initially but MATLAB automatically took it as zero order hold because I didn't specify any kind of hold. The result for the zero order hold is different from the expected result. I’m not trying to use any hold in my discretization. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation
https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/c2d.html
and figure what discretization method you want, since you clearly don't want zoh

> sysd = c2d(sysc,Ts,method)

The following methods are available, and each will have its pros and cons:

- zoh
- least-squares
- matched
- tustin
- impulse
- foh